# How can I get data from parent component to child component in Angular?

Tags: angular, setter, getter

I just started to study Angular and very beginner.
I am using Angular 7 and I would like to send data from parent component to child component. The parent component send data by `async await`. I used this `[carInfo]="data"` in parent component html and 
receive the data at child component such as below code.
However, the problem is I cannot get the data. If I put `console.log(this._railcarData)` at `ngOnInit(){}` the console window response 'undefined' but If I put it at `set railcarData(){}` I could see the data after finished `ngOnInit(){}`. I know this is because of the async but I couldn't find any solution for this. Please any body let me help what I exactly study more and how can I use the data for my project?

```
private _railcarData: RailcarModel[];
@Input() 
set railcarData(value: RailcarModel[]) {
    this._railcarData = value;
}
get railcarData() {
    return this._railcarData;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the html and the ts code of your parent component?

Comment: Yes I did. It needs a time for getting data

Comment: But I don't know how to get it and use it

Comment: As you wanted data asynchronously  passed into child component, you can make an observable in your `service` file which returns `Observable<RailcarModel[]>` and then subscribe to the data in child component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the data is passed into child component asynchronously, you can make use of subscription

In `some.service.ts`

```
private _railcarData = new Subject<RailcarModel[]>();
_railcarData$ = this._railcarData.asObservable();

setRailCarData(data: RailcarModel[]) {
   this._railcarData.next(data);
}

// Async HTTP Call
fetchRailData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .get<any>('/api/someurl')
      .pipe(
        tap((data: any) => {   // You can set data here or in parentcomponent.ts
          this.setRailCarData(data); // Assigns value to subject
        })
    );
}
```

In `childcomponent.ts` file

```
railDataSubscription: Subscription;
constructor(private someHttpService: SomeService) {
    this.railDataSubscription = this.someHttpService._railcarData$.subscribe(
      raildata => {
        this.railcarData(raildata); // your set method
      }
    );
  }

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.railDataSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

In `parentcomponent.ts` file // Optional as data is assigned in http call itself

```
constructor(private someHttpService: SomeService) {}

// This line in async subscription
this.someHttpService.setRailCarData(railddata);
```